# Get random rows if full text result is less than N rows

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am using below code to find something

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('php tutorial') LIMIT 25
```

If there are titles that match my query, It returns 25 rows. If the row is empty or if less than 25 rows I want to get random 25 rows from table. Is it possible in a **single query**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY MATCH(title) AGAINST('php tutorial') DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Note that this could be *much* more expensive, depending on the size of your data because the entire table needs to be sorted.

A more efficient method would be:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.*, MATCH(title) AGAINST('php tutorial') as score
       from table t
       where MATCH(title) AGAINST('php tutorial')
       limit 25
      ) union all
      (select g.*, -1 as score
       from table g
       where NOT (MATCH(title) AGAINST('php tutorial'))
       limit 25
      )
     ) t
order by score desc
limit 25;
```

This limits the overall sorting to at most 50 records.  Like your original query, it does not guarantee the highest scoring titles will be returned.

Comment: can you explain what is t ? I get error Unknown table 't' ?

Comment: It is a table alias.  In the second subquery, it should be spelled "g" ;)